# Replace browser content with new URL

Tags: javascript

I need to reload the browser window with a new URL which also will replace/flush content and force reload of the page. window.replace() or window.location doesn't work, any other function I could use ?

Comment: Why don't window.replace and window.location work?

Comment: Are you looking to flush the cache?

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com/");
```

Other ways (but not replacing):

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/";
window.location.assign("http://example.com/");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
location.href="http://www.example.com";
```

There is also

```
location.replace="http://www.example.com";
```

The latter doesn't mess with the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

You meen if I use Ajax navigation. I can use this code. and i will be able to use back button to navigate the previous page?